# Regex for email showing the first and last letters of the user and domain

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regex and I am trying to substitute some characters for asterisk in php like below:

email: `victor@gmail.com` -> `v****r@g***l.com`

I have done this:

```
$email = preg_replace('/(?:^|@).\K|\.[^@]*$(*SKIP)(*F)|.(?=.*?\.)/', '*', $linha['cli_email']);
```

The problem is that the output is `v*****@g****.com` instead of `v****r@g***l.com` and I don't know how to show the last for the username and last for the email provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 $email = preg_replace('/(?:^|.@).\K|.\.[^@]*$(*SKIP)(*F)|.(?=.*?\.)/', '*', $linha['cli_email']);
```

Hope it helped..

Comment: if `v@gmail.com` ?

Comment: No it returns `v*****r@g****l.com`, I just checked again to be sure

Comment: This point that was added made the difference.Thank you very much!

Comment: `v@gmail.com` => `v******l.com`

Comment: Not great with user@host.example.com either

Answer (score 2):

Here first of all we are matching string using regex.

**Regex:** `(?<=\b[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=.\@)|(?<=@.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=.\.)`

> `(?<=\b[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=.\@)` says match characters positive looking ahead for `one character` and `@` and positive looking backward for `boundary condition` and `a character`.
>
> `(?<=@.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=.\.)` says match characters positive looking ahead for `one character` and `.` and positive looking backward for `@` condition and a character`.`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/782626)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$email="victor@gmail.com";
preg_match_all('/(?<=\b[a-z])[a-z]+(?=.\@)|(?<=@.)[a-z]+(?=.\.)/',$email,$matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $key => $value)
{
    $email=str_replace($value, getStars(strlen($value)), $email);
}
echo $email;
function getStars($length)
{
    $string="";
    for($x=0;$x<$length;$x++)
    {
        $string.="*";
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: (?<=\b.).+(?=.\@)|(?<=@.).+(?=.\.)  - email can contain digits

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Putting together your answer and the above I understood better regex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be accounting for all types of email address. How will the accepted answer handle email addresses like `m@example.com` or `user@host.example.com` or  or `joe@m.com`?

```
<?php
function starmid($str) {
    switch (strlen($str)) {
        case 0: return false;
        case 1: return $str;
        case 2: return $str[0] . "*";
        default: return $str[0] . str_repeat("*", strlen($str) - 2) . substr($str, -1);
    }
}
function hideemail($email) {
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return false;
    }
    list($u, $d) = explode("@", $email);
    $d = explode(".", $d);
    $tld = array_pop($d);
    $d = implode(".", $d);
    return starmid($u) . "@" . starmid($d) . ".$tld";
}

$emails = [
    "victor@gmail.com",
    "v@example.com",
    "victor@g.com",
    "victor@host.example.com",
    "victor+foo@gmail.com",
    "invalid@",
];

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    echo hideemail($email) . "\n";
}
```